# Hazelcast IMap performance

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I use the hazelcast 3.8.6.
There is a IMAP{Key, Value} with next settings:

```
mapConfig.setBackupCount(5);
mapConfig.setReadBackupData(true);
```

the Key is

```
long userId;
long contentId;
```

also there are 5 nodes where the data is. As far as I understand according  the setting each node will be have all data. Such way I turn a distributed map to a replicated map to increase speed of get operations and don't do networking calls.

let's imagine I need get all data for user by id. in usual mode I would write next code:

```
EntryObject eo = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
Predicate predicate = eo.key().get("this.userId").equal(userId);
map.values(predicate).stream().map(.....)
```

this code will be executed on all nodes and result will be returned to node which make the call. Am I right understanding that in case of the settings "setReadBackupData(true)" the request won't be send to other nodes and all data will be found on node which make this request? or in that case to avoid networking calls I just should use something like this:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
.filter(entry->entry.getKey().getUserId().equals(userId))
.map(.....)
```

thanks.

Comment: Backup count of 5 means 6 copies (master+5). If you only have 5 nodes then you've requested one copy too many.

Comment: And read-from-backup is only available for key-based access, not queries.

Comment: `entrySet()` is risky in general as that's everything, when an `IMap` is partitioned usually because it's big. What problem are you trying to solve ? Find all keys by partial key ? What does your `map(....)`  do with them

Comment: noctarius,  did i understand you correctly that in " read-from-backup" if i make map.entrySet() call, data will be got from this node bacause of it is key-based access? no networking call

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve ? To find some keys by partial key ? You can search on key so `entrySet()` could be `entrySet(predicate)` which would reduce the wire transfer

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the readBackupData flag works only if you execute the query from within a Member, so if you are using a HazelcastClient, then it will not read from backup.